# Google App Engine for Java, What is for .Net?

Tags: .net, google-app-engine, hosting, cloud, appharbor

Google App Engine is a cloud computing architecture that supports java based web services to be deployed.

What cloud computing hosting options are available for .Net web developers ?

Comment: How is this spam?

Comment: I don't get why it is transparently spam.

Comment: I wish I could actually rewrite this guys question instead of just re-tagging it.  I suspect the asker is a non naive English speaker and so it got mistaken for spam.

Comment: I smoothed out the grammar a little bit so that people will hopefully not mistake this for spam.

Comment: i am not a spammer.. how do you describe a spammer.. i had the above question  in my mind for a long time and asked it here hoping for an answer..  BTW, what questions do you call as spam.. you call true questions as spam ????????

Comment: It is not spam. It was just worded a little strangely, which confused some people into thinking that it was an advertisement for GAE or Azure.

Comment: ok.. :-) i just got disappointed by the fact that my most fav community 'stackoverflow' calling me a spammer/a bad guy .. BTW is azure reliable for hosting ?

Comment: There's also [AppHarbor](https://appharbor.com/).

Answer (score 23, accepted):

That would be Microsoft's Azure

http://www.microsoft.com/azure/default.mspx

Comment: pricing came out very recently: http://blogs.msdn.com/windowsazure/archive/2009/07/14/confirming-commercial-availability-and-announcing-business-model.aspx

Comment: It is being released as a commercial product, so I would imagine they will make it as stable and reliable as they can.

Answer (score 9):

[Amazon](http://aws.amazon.com/windows/) also supports Windows - for example [AWS Elastic Beanstock](http://aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/) has features similar to the other PaaS offerings mentioned in this thread.

Answer (score 5):

Apart from Azure there is also [**AppHarbor**](http://appharbor.com/), which actually runs on Amazon infrastructure.

Answer (score 4):

As other have said you're looking for the [Windows Azure Platform](http://www.microsoft.com/azure/).  The platform consists of the following components:

- Windows Azure: Cloud services OS
- .Net Services: Services Bus, Access Control Service, Workflow Service
- SQL Azure: Cloud database storage, can store database up to 10GB in size as announced at WPDC '09
- Live Services: Windows Live integration

The pricing for the could services was announced earlier today at WPDC 2009 and in addition they announced that it would become commerically available at the Professional Developers Conference (PDC) later this year.  Util then these services are available free of charge in the form of a Community Technical Preview.

Answer (score 3):

http://www.microsoft.com/azure/default.mspx

Azure.

Answer (score 2):

Apprenda (http://www.apprenda.com). You can run it where ever you want and instantly have a PaaS. Layer it ontop of EC2 and away you go!

Answer (score 1):

As of May 11, 2016, Google Compute Engine supports the .NET platform (okay, Compute Engine is a IaaS and not a Paas, like App Engine):

[How to get your ASP.NET app up on Google Cloud the easy way](https://cloudplatform.googleblog.com/2016/05/how-to-get-your-ASP-NET-app-up-on-Google-Cloud-the-easy-way.html)

> Don’t let anyone tell you that Google Cloud Platform doesn’t support a wide range of platforms and programming languages. We kicked things off with Python and Java on Google App Engine, then PHP and Go. Now, we support .NET framework on Google Compute Engine.